# get file names, time stamps and MD5 checksums from a log file

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I want to write a bash script, that will take the output of a log file and extract the relevant content to another log file, which I will used to do statistical analysis of the time it takes to send a file as an example:

The content is as follows:

```
FileSize  TimeStamp         MD5          Full Path to File
4824597   2013-06-21 11:26  5a264...c11  ...45/.../.../ITAM.xml 
4824597   2013-06-20 23:18  5a264...c11  ...48/.../.../1447_rO8iKD.TMP.ITAM.xml
```

I am trying to extract the **TimeStamp** and the **Full Path** to the File.

I am a beginner in scripting but so far I have tried:

```
    cat "/var/log/Customer.log" | grep '2013* *11' >> test.txt
```

Are there other methods I'm missing.  Thank you very much.

Comment: cat "/var/log/Customer.log" | grep '2013* *11' >> test.txt

Comment: True @lhf, `grep expr /var/log/Customer.log >> test.txt` would have done. But be nice please :P

Comment: The most obvious problem is that you don't close your quote, is that just a typo in the question? What specifically are you trying to match, it's hard to tell from your mistaken attempt.

Comment: @Barmar yes it was just a typo.  I updated the question because I was asking it incorrectly please help me on the update.

Comment: I've fixed the typo, but you still haven't clarified. `grep` is for selecting lines, which lines are you trying to match? `2013` looks like the year, but what is `11` -- the hour, day, or something else?

Comment: @Barmar I believe it was the end of the md5 code I truncated. Let me put that back in.

Comment: Is `awk '$2~/^2013/{$1=$4="";print}' /var/log/Customer.log` what you're looking for?

Comment: @icedwater Are you going to put something back in?

Comment: Yeah, I put ..c11 back in the end of the MD5 column, but if the reviewer doesn't accept such a trivial edit, I'm fine with that too.

Comment: Why only MD5 ending with `11`? That seems like a pretty random criteria to select log messages.

Comment: I made a new question if you all would be willing to help 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245135/how-to-subtract-the-difference-of-two-timestamps-in-a-2-log-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want extract the TimeStamp and the Full Path for all entries then this should work:

```
awk 'NR>1{print $2,$3,$NF}' inputFile > outputFile
```

Comment: When the time is saved off into test.txt, is there a way to save the timestamp in an array for example and then run a loop to subtract the timestamp from another arrayed set of timestamps?

Comment: @user2019182 Yes, you will have to use `mktime()` function. Deleting timestamps as is will be painful.

Comment: I made a new question here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245135/how-to-subtract-the-difference-of-two-timestamps-in-a-2-log-files

Answer (score 2):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -nr '2,$ {s/\S+\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+\S+\s+(.*)/\1 \2\t\3/;p}' file
```

---

```
$cat file
FileSize  TimeStamp         MD5          Full Path to File
4824597   2013-06-21 11:26  5a264...c11  ...45/.../.../ITAM.xml
4824597   2013-06-20 23:18  5a264...c11  ...48/.../.../1447_rO8iKD.TMP.ITAM.xml

$sed -nr '2,$ {s/\S+\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+\S+\s+(.*)/\1 \2\t\3/;p}' file
2013-06-21 11:26        ...45/.../.../ITAM.xml
2013-06-20 23:18        ...48/.../.../1447_rO8iKD.TMP.ITAM.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is what you want:

```
awk '$2 ~ /^2013/ && $4 ~ /11$/ { print $2, $3, $NF; }' /var/log/Customer.log > test.txt
```

- `$2 ~ /^2013/` matches dates beginning with 2013
- `$4 ~ /11$/` matches MD5 ending with 11
- `print $2, $3, $NF` prints fields 2 (date), 3 (time), and the last field (pathname)

If these regular expressions are confusing to you, go to [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info) and read the tutorial.

Comment: When the time is saved off into test.txt, is there a way to save the timestamp in an array for example and then run a loop to subtract the timestamp from another arrayed set of timestamps?

Comment: Yes, you can add to an array, and then use the `END` block in `awk` to process the array at the end. But isn't that what the statistical analysis script does?

Comment: Thats what I want to make it do ideally lol.  I am in the process of writing it.

Comment: So far this is what I have helped from another user on stack overflow:
*Code*
 










    awk '{       
      sub(/:/," ",$2);
      t1=mktime(strftime("%Y %m %d")" "$2" 00");
      getline < "/root/ITAM.txt";
      sub(/:/," ",$2) 
      t2=mktime(strftime("%Y %m %d")" "$2" 00");
      print $3": "t2-t1" s"
      }' /root/fileSizelog.txt'

Comment: It's really hard to read code in comments. If you're having a new problem, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the columns are tab-separated, you can just use `cut`:

```
cut -f2,4 /var/log/Customer.log | grep -v MD5 >> test.txt
```

will append columns 2 and 4 (counting starts at 1) into the `test.txt`. Lines containing `MD5` will be removed by the `grep` invocation.

Comment: You need to filter out the heading line.

Comment: True, that could just be another step later on though. Like the `grep` I added in belatedly. It feels simpler than your `awk` call, though I should really learn more `awk`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245135/how-to-subtract-the-difference-of-two-timestamps-in-a-2-log-files

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
awk 'NR!=1 {print $2 " " $3 "\t" $5}' Customer.log > stat.txt
```

Comment: When the time is saved off into test.txt, is there a way to save the timestamp in an array for example and then run a loop to subtract the timestamp from another arrayed set of timestamps?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245135/how-to-subtract-the-difference-of-two-timestamps-in-a-2-log-files