# How to subtract the difference of two timestamps in a 2 log files

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, awk, grep

I am trying to find how long it takes to send a file through my system: I have the time stamps logged in two log files as follows:

first

```
4824597 1371853829 /home/customer1/ITAM.xml
.
.
.
.
4824597 1371854003 /home/customer46/ITAM.xml
```

second

```
4824597 1371854003 /home/customer1/ITAM.xml
.
.
.
.
4824597 1371854003 /home/customer46/ITAM.xml
```

Below are the commands I am using to subtract the timestamps.

```
awk '{
  sub(/:/," ",$2);
  t1=mktime(strftime("%Y %m %d")" "$2" 00");
  getline < "/root/ITAM.txt";
  sub(/:/," ",$2);
  t2=mktime(strftime("%Y %m %d")" "$2" 00");
  print $3": "t2-t1" s"
}' /root/fileSizelog.txt
```

The problem I am having now is that I am getting strange outputs like -7185759 s.  It seems like it is doing the diff from EPOCH time.  Can anyone please help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash Script to take the timestamp of a logged files and subtract it from the timestamp of another log file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241982/bash-script-to-take-the-timestamp-of-a-logged-files-and-subtract-it-from-the-tim)

Comment: I asked the original one.  I'm new to stackoverflow, I have new info that changed the content so I made a new question.

Comment: @user2019182 You should refine your questions.  Not keep posting new ones with updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>You mentioned in the question that there are two log files even though you posted only one. So I will take your input data as an example to show how you can work your way to a solution.</strike>

Updated the solution based on new sample data.

#### Sample data used:

```
$ cat first
824597 1371853829 /home/customer1/ITAM.xml
4824597 1371854003 /home/customer46/ITAM.xml

$ cat second
4824597 1371854003 /home/customer1/ITAM.xml
4824597 1371854003 /home/customer46/ITAM.xml
```

I have added comments to make it a little easier to understand.

#### Content of script.awk:

```
# This syntax in combination with next (seen below) allows us to work on the first file 
# entirely 
 
NF==FNR {

# we are indexing the filename and assign it start time value

    start[$3]=$2

# next allows us to skip the rest action statements

    next
}

# once the first log file is looped over we store the second log file in end array

{

    end[$3]=$2
} 

# End block is where we are doing most of our computation since we have scanned 
# through the two files and now are ready to calculate the difference

END {

# we iterate over the start array and pick an index value (that is a file)

    for (filestart in start) {

# we do the same for our second array

        for (fileend in end) {

# if the filename are same then we are ready to do the difference

        if (filestart == fileend) {

# we subtract start time from end time

            diff = end[fileend] - start[filestart];

# we use sprintf function to avoid printing the difference so that we can store it in a variable

            diff = sprintf("%dh:%dm:%ds",diff/(60*60),diff%(60*60)/60,diff%60)

# we print the filename and the time lag

            print filestart,diff

# we delete the filename indices to reduce the size of array for performance reasons
    
            delete start[filestart]
            delete end[fileend]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Either run the script as `awk -f script.awk log.file` or run it as:

```
$ awk '        
NR==FNR {
    start[$3]=$2
    next
} 
{
    end[$3]=$2
} 
END {
    for(filestart in start) {
        for(fileend in end) {
            if (filestart == fileend) {
                diff = end[fileend] - start[filestart];
                diff = sprintf("%dh:%dm:%ds",diff/(60*60),diff%(60*60)/60,diff%60)
                print filestart,diff
                delete start[filestart]
                delete end[fileend]
             }
        }
    }
}' first second
/home/customer46/ITAM.xml 0h:0m:0s
/home/customer1/ITAM.xml 0h:2m:54s
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will test it out first thing in the morning.  The table above is actually 2 log files, the gap without the ...'s is how they are distinguised.  Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: @user2019182 You're welcome. I have made necessary changes to the answer based on your updated question and sample data. Good luck

Comment: Hey it worked well, thank you.  In the script can I print the file size as well? what would the size flag be? print filestart,diff,

Comment: You're welcome. To get the file size you can use `start[$1"\t"$3]` and end[$1"\t"$3] as your arrays. Rest everything should be same. I just noticed in your sample data though file name was same for `ITAM.xml` but size was different. In such event it will not print that.